# My GitHub Actions Merge Queue seems to be set up, but auto merges without checks

Tags: git, github-actions

I have a simple GitHub action set up in my GitHub with a yml file:

```
name: Test Suite
on:
  pull_request:
    - develop
    - patches/*
  merge_group:

jobs:
  call-code-tests:
    name: Run Base Code Tests
    uses: ./.github/workflows/code-tests.yml
    secrets:
      ...
```

So this was set up.  In my settings I figured I needed to set up some additional information.   I was hoping that this would just work, but when going into Settings > Branches, I figured I might need to create a branch protection rule for these two branches.

I set a rule for develop that says:

- Require Status Checks to Merge

  - Require Branches to be Up to Date before Merge
- Require Merge Queue

  - Squash and Merge
  - Build concurrency: 5
  - Merge Limits, minimum: 1 PR or 5 minutes
  - Max PR to Merge: 5

I thought that implementing the Actions would just auto create blockers.  Do I essentially set up all the various actions, and then define it in the Settings as blockers or is there another way to do it?

Similarly, we have a series of patch branches, which I have set up for PR to `patches/*` but I noticed that patch branches themselves won't let us make rules for them because settings > branch protections > pattern doesn't accept wildcards.

Edit:  I created a new Branch Rule, and it was OK with a wildcard.